# Is it possible to use Boost.Asio with -fnoexcept

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I would like to integrate Boost.Asio (or even just non-Boost Asio) in to my application. This application is compiled with `-fnoexcept`. In previous versions of Boost.Asio, there were overloads using `boost::system::error_code` that have since been deprecated. I am curious if:

- Is error handling of Asio errors (ignore exceptions from user code - that is already exception free in my case) purely exception based? Or are there stronger exception guarantees (as in Asio will not throw exceptions, only user code can do so)
- Will compiling Boost.Asio with `-fnoexceptions` have any unintended consequences (is the library still even usable at this point)?

Comment: I can't see any deprecations in the docs, is there a specific function you are looking at?

Comment: I was looking at an older version of Boost.Asio docs (shipped with boost 1.68.0). It appears to have been completely removed from both Boost.Asio and non-Boost Asio in the latest stable release. I will edit my question to just ask about compiling with `-fnoexceptions`.

Comment: Have you tried it? Pretty sure there are still error code overloads for every operation

Comment: think-async says [_"(Note: Boost.Asio 1.20.0 is also included in Boost 1.77.)"_](https://think-async.com/Asio/#:~:text=Boost.Asio%201.20.0%20is%20also%20included%20in%20Boost%201.77). I can confirm all the error-code overloads I expect are present in Boost 1.78

Comment: Ahh I was looking at the constructor of `io_context`, not the `run` method. You can see in the docs [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload2.html) that there is a deprecation message.